# reduce even array in half by merging columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Assuming i have the following array:

```
a = array([[[4, 8, 7, 3, 1, 2],
        [3, 1, 8, 7, 1, 9],
        [0, 0, 3, 0, 7, 6],
        [1, 1, 5, 0, 5, 1],
        [1, 6, 7, 0, 6, 2]],

       [[8, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [2, 8, 1, 6, 4, 9],
        [1, 8, 7, 2, 2, 2],
        [6, 6, 2, 6, 0, 5],
        [3, 2, 2, 0, 6, 8]],

       [[4, 6, 3, 2, 1, 4],
        [0, 4, 3, 5, 9, 4],
        [1, 4, 6, 7, 2, 4],
        [6, 3, 5, 7, 7, 8],
        [1, 0, 3, 9, 2, 5]],

       [[7, 7, 3, 9, 7, 0],
        [8, 5, 1, 4, 3, 9],
        [9, 7, 9, 5, 4, 9],
        [2, 0, 6, 0, 8, 5],
        [4, 4, 4, 7, 5, 2]],

       [[4, 0, 8, 2, 1, 0],
        [2, 4, 0, 7, 3, 7],
        [4, 6, 8, 7, 9, 6],
        [3, 2, 7, 5, 2, 3],
        [7, 6, 3, 0, 1, 5]]])
```

Is there an easy way to reduce the column values by summing to get the following array:

```
b = array([[[12, 10, 3],
        [4, 15, 10],
        [0, 3, 13],
        [2, 5, 6],
        [7, 7, 8]],
        
           ...])
```

The first row is achieved by:[4+8, 7+3, 1+2]. I know we can use np.sum to merge columns but I am lost on how to select the right columns to add together. Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do simply this:

```
a.reshape((5,5,3,2)).sum(axis=-1)
```

`reshape((5,5,3,2))` will 'split' the last dimension into groups of 2, the `sum(axis=-1)` will sum over that last freshly created dimension.

In the general case (if the dimensions of `a` change) you can also use

```
a.reshape(a.shape[:-1]+(-1,2)).sum(axis=-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with simple numpy slicing.

```py
b = a[:,:,::2] + a[:,:,1::2]
```

This tells us to select the whole array, and at the last dimension select the even columns, then the odd columns, and add them together elementwise.